# State the overall alpha after interium analyses

Tags: statistical-significance, clinical-trials, optimal-stopping

Suppose a trial investigator wants to analyse the primary outcome (morning peak flow at 6 months) after the trial has been running for 1 year, 18 months and 2 years using alpha=0.05 each time, and will stop the trial early if a significant result is obtained on any one of these occasions.

State the overall alpha that would apply to the primary outcome in this case?

How could you control the overall alpha to be 0.05?